# Save webpage fully (with images, css, etc), better like web archive

Tags: php, mhtml

I would like to make a local copy of web page(s) using PHP. This can be a web archive, like mht, or just an html with images and css. The result should be nearly the same as you press "Save as" button in your browser :)

I have found such library to do this:
http://freecode.com/projects/php-save-complete-html-page
Finally it creates one big html file, but works very-very slow and creates a really huge file.

I found such solution in the net, but it also does not work:

```
wget --no-parent --timestamping --convert-links --page-requisites --no-directories --no-host-directories -erobots=off http://cnn.com
```

It does not create any images, does not download css, just download html only

I would like to find some PHP library that can help me to copy web page fully, or to find some external tool, to what I can do an API cal and get MHT archive, for example

Comment: OK, now we come closer. So what _is_ it you want to know? What _is_ your problem in this, since your obviously know what you are talking about?

Comment: I would like to find some PHP library that can help me to copy web page fully, or to find some external tool, to what I can do an API cal and get MHT archive, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to write your own, you can use curl and search for external urls, then recursively follow those. There may be a library out there.

Otherwise, you can use `exec()` in php to run a command-line program. HTTrack does a good job at achiving websites:
http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html

So, for example:

`exec('httrack "http://www.all.net/" -O "/tmp/www.all.net" "+*.all.net/*" -v');`

In addition, if you'd like to use `wget`, [I found a set of options that should work](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget) (allegedly as I haven't tried it):

```
wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains example.com \
     --no-parent \
         www.example.com/directoryToArchive
```